# Decompose ${\mathbb{Z}_n}^{*} / ({\mathbb{Z}_n}^{*})^2$ into a direct sum of cyclic groups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, cyclic-decomposition

Decompose ${\mathbb{Z}_n}^{*} / ({\mathbb{Z}_n}^{*})^2$ into a direct sum of cyclic groups,

Where $({\mathbb{Z}_n}^{*})^2 = \left\{a^2 \ : \ a \in {\mathbb{Z}_n}^{*} \right\}$,

A) when $n$ is an odd prime $p$,

B) when $n$ is a product of two distinct prime $p$, and $q$.

I think that they are just $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Since, if $n=p$ an odd prime, ${\mathbb{Z}_p}^{*} = \left\{ 1, \ 2, \ ... , \ p-1\right\}$, then $({\mathbb{Z}_p}^{*})^2 = \left\{ 1^2, \ 2^2, \ ... . \ (\frac{p-1}{2})^2 \right\}$.

Then ${\mathbb{Z}_p}^{*} / ({\mathbb{Z}_p}^{*})^2 \cong \mathbb{Z} _2$

Similarly, if $n = pq$ for distinct prime $p$ and $q$, ${\mathbb{Z}_{pq}}^{*} = \mathbb{Z}_{(p-1)(q-1)}$.

And if $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{pq}^{*}$, then should $pq-m$ be too.

Clearly, their squares modulo $pq$ is exactly same. So $(\mathbb{Z}_{pq}^{*})^2$ should be $ \mathbb{Z}_{\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{2}}$.

So is this case, $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}^{*} / (\mathbb{Z}_{pq}^{*})^2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

It seems to me, then, no matter what $n$ is, $\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*} / (\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*})^2 $ is congruent to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Where have I done wrong thing? What is wrong?

Comment: Try $n=3\cdot 5$.

Comment: @lhf Thanks you! I've already calculated this case, but there were mis-calculation.

Comment: @lhf apart from this case, if $n$ is a prime, then is my conclusion right?

Comment: You are right that $m^2=(pq-m)^2$ and so you found two solutions to $x^2=m^2$. You are wrong to think that the equation $x^2=b$ has at most two solutions. This property holds only for fields and $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ is not a field, unlike $\mathbb{Z}_p$. In other words your conclusion about the form of $(\mathbb{Z}_{pq}^*)^2$ is wrong, in fact more than $2$ elements can square to the same element. Meaning $(\mathbb{Z}_{pq}^*)^2$ is smaller than you think.